# Can't select next year on ionic 2 datetime picker?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

i'm working with ionic 2. The problem is this[image]

on `ion-datetime` why it can't select next year for example i want to select 2018. And this is my script to set the ion-datetime

`<ion-datetime displayFormat="MMM/DD/YYYY" pickerFormat="MMM/DD/YYYY" [min]="mindate"></ion-datetime>`

[click here for example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-wgqoxe?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html)

Comment: It would be helpful if you can show the problem using [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com).

Comment: @BennyChan i've mad an example check it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `max`

```
<ion-datetime displayFormat="MMM/DD/YYYY" pickerFormat="MMM/DD/YYYY" [min]="mindate" max="2050"></ion-datetime>
```

Comment: Wah that so simple. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is example

**Min and Max Datetimes**

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Date</ion-label>
  <ion-datetime displayFormat="MMMM YYYY" min="2016" max="2020-10-31" [(ngModel)]="myDate">
  </ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```

learn more about it http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/datetime/DateTime/